# Is the limit w.r.t. $L^2$ norm the same as pointwise limit?

Tags: functional-analysis

It seems very intuitive that if a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ in $C[0, 1]$ converges with respect to the $L^2$ norm to a function $f \in C[0,1]$ and converges pointwise to a function $g$ then the two limits are same. The proof of the case where $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $g$ is quite straightforward. Any hints as to how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = x^n$. What continuous function does it converge to in $L^2$ norm? What function does it converge to pointwise?

Comment: You can conclude that $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Recall that any $L^2$-convergent sequence has a subsequence which converges almost everywhere to the same limit.